# Can I control external application using C#

Tags: c#

Currently I have a software installed on my computer. It is a time clock software whereby user scan their card and then I bring the scanner and connect to my computer and use the software to extract the information.

Is it possible for me to write a C# application to control the time clock software so that I can automate the process of extracting user's information?

The time clock software was bought from external vendor.

Comment: If the time clock software has an API that you can talk to in some way from the C# application, and that API has a provision for extracting user information, then yes, it is possible.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is easy if they provide libraries which you can use. You have to give us more information. What kind of software is it?

Comment: Depending on how the application is written you could also use PInvoke and windows messages to control the application. It's ugly but works for apps that use the standard Win32 controls.

Comment: do you have access to the files your app generates? does have network connectivity? what platform was it written on?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things.

Does the external vendor provide an API to tap into the application or data? Maybe ask them if they do. Some developers don't give this information automatically. If so you can just look through the documentation.

Does the application save files you can open and take information from? If they save in a text format like txt or xml you can simply make a txt/xml parser that reads the file and do what-ever you want with it.

If not it gets nasty. Sniffing network to look at packages (if it sends them), hacking the software to make some changes. All in all not worth the trouble.